# Drop unwanted connections

Tags: nginx, bots

I want to block unwanted Bots from accessing sites on the server.

Can nginx drop / kill the connection right away when a certain Bot is detected?

```
if ($http_user_agent ~ (agent1|agent2) ) {
    **KILL CONNECTION**;
}
```

Something like example above.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use return 444; [This non-standard status code of 444 causes nginx to simply close the connection without responding to it](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return).

```
if ($http_user_agent ~ (agent1|agent2) ) {
    return 444;
}
```

- [Reference documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return)
- [More elaborative documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#how_to_prevent_undefined_server_names)

Comment: nginx [documentation about 444](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#how_to_prevent_undefined_server_names)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it can.  See the question below - this redirects based on an agent string, but you can really do whatever you want (error page or whatever).

[Nginx proxy or rewrite depending on user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627596/nginx-proxy-or-rewrite-depending-on-user-agent)

However, please note - that a decent bot will fake its user-agent string to look just like a normal browser, so this is by no means a robust way to deter bots from sweeping your site.

Comment: This question is about dropping the connection, which you do not talk about at all. The example code in the question already handles user agent decision, so that’s not even unclear.

Answer (score -3):

```
server {
  listen 8443 default ssl;
  error_page 404 403 = 444; #disconnect if 404 or 403
  root /srv/empty;  #Empty forder
  ...
  ...

  location /summary_report{
        root /srv/www;
        index index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```

https://127.0.0.1/                               Disconnect.
https://127.0.0.1/summary_report     Not disconnect.

Comment: This just attempts to serve /444 in a redirect loop.

Comment: Pretty sure you want the error at the end of the config file for this to work, though I could be wrong