# How to block in NGINX all request starting with question mark

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

My website is getting attacked with such request as

```
66.249.75.242 - - [12/Jan/2023:00:29:11 +0800] "GET /?bailiffry/1529595 HTTP/1.1" 200 57100 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.5304.115 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.75.236 - - [12/Jan/2023:00:29:14 +0800] "GET /?Diphysite-7105-hwfLs/328609048 HTTP/1.1" 200 57097 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.75.236 - - [12/Jan/2023:00:29:16 +0800] "GET /?hypothermal/sealant313919.html HTTP/1.1" 200 57100 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.5304.115 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.75.236 - - [12/Jan/2023:00:29:17 +0800] "GET /?dianilid/elated357845.html HTTP/1.1" 200 57100 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.5304.115 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

I have blocked other patterns, I just wish to block this for now as I have been solving this for hours and wish a quick fix for now.

How do I block request starting with question mark?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. See the question below
[Drop unwanted connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709549/drop-unwanted-connections)

```
if (condition) ) {
    return 444;
}
```

You Can also put a WAF (Web Application Firewall) in your front, if your request is coming for a security issue you're facing.
you can see [NAXSI](https://github.com/nbs-system/naxsi). It's Open-source and compatible with any nginx version.

Comment: apologies, I updated my question as it is incomplete.  I wish to block those starting with question mark. Just tired and forgot